# How can one print the current state of the resource chain?

Tags: macos, resources, macos-carbon

The [Resource Manager Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Resource_Manager/Reference/reference.html) says:

> The Resource Manager keeps track of
>   resources in memory and provides
>   functions for the proper management of
>   the resource chain.

Is there a way to inspect the resource chain from GDB- to print it's current state, etc.? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eric Schlegel answered the question on the Carbon-Dev mailing list in this [message](http://lists.apple.com/archives/carbon-dev/2011/Mar/msg00012.html)

It was:

```
(gdb) call (void)PrintResourceChain(0)
The parameter should be 0 or 1: 0 for walking the resource map data structures directly, 1 for using API to walk the resource chain.
```

He also notes that it may not be documented anywhere.